# How to check which implicits are ambiguous?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I have following implicit conversions defined, which helps me porting some Javascript code to Scala:

```
  case class NullableBoolean(value: Boolean)

  implicit def toNullable(boolean: Boolean) = NullableBoolean(boolean)
  implicit def toBoolean(boolean: NullableBoolean) = boolean != null && boolean.value
```

The code is then used like this:

```
class SomeClass {
  var x: NullableBoolean = _

  def set(v: Boolean): Unit = {
    x = v
  }

  def someOtherFunction(): Unit = {
    if (x) println("Yes")
    else print("No")
  }
}

val some = new SomeClass

some.someOtherFunction()
some.set(true)
some.someOtherFunction()
```

When used in a small sample everything works fine. However when used in the real project, I get error:

> Error:(360, 16) type mismatch;
>
> found   : xxx.NullableBoolean
>
> required: Boolean
>
> ```
>  if (this.someValue) {
> ```

I suspect this is because of some other implicit conversion imported which makes the conversion ambiguous, but I am unable to find it. Is there some method or tool which would show me the eligible conversions or otherwise help me determining the ambiguity? I have tried IntelliJ Shift-Ctrl-Q, but it shows me only my conversion to Boolean and some conversions to String, which looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit conversions can not be ambiguous. The compiler would complain if there are multiple conversions in scope matching.

Can you confirm the toBoolean conversion is indeed in scope when calling `this.someValue` ?

Comment: Yes, it is in scope. When I use it as `toBoolean(this.someValue)`, it works fine.

Comment: As I said, I was unable to find and ambiguous implicit when searching for it. Perhaps there is some other reason why compiler does not use it, but I fail to see it. The function is in scope and it is implicit, the same code works fine in a standalone sample, but not in the real project.

Comment: Does if (this.someValue == true) change anything ?

Comment: Well, it compiles, but == compiles for anything. I am given warning "Comparing unrelated types" by the IDE, though. I am unable to check what comparison implementation gets called run-time, as the project currently contains other errors preventing it compiling.

Comment: Can you create an example which you can post here which produces the error?